# What did complex analysis teach us about the real numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, real-numbers

Are there interesting properties of the real numbers that only become apparent when realizing them as a subset of the complex numbers?

Comment: A lot of: famos $\sqrt{-1}$, roots for polynomial with real coefficients, negative logarithm etc. - a lot of.

Comment: It's probably the easiest way to show that every polynomial can be factored over the reals into a product of linear and quadratic polynomials.

Comment: $n^{th}$ degree polynomial has $n$ roots.

Comment: Complex eigenvalues of real matrices can tell a lot, e.g. about stability and oscillatory behavior of linear dynamic systems.

Comment: What about convergence of series?

Comment: @herbsteinberg this isnt true for the real numbers

Comment: @user404111 I guess I wasn't clear enough.  What I meant was that you need complex numbers to get all the roots.